Lookup values based on multiple if statements in Power Query
I have two tables of Active Directory users:
Extract AD on Prem
Email                       NHA_Derived_Responsible_Manager  Fullname    is_zz_em_  Purpose
zz_em_john.smith@mail.com   null                             John Smith  Yes        Business Continuity
zz_em_jane.doe@mail.com     null                             Jane Doe    Yes        Meeting Room
johndoeadmin@mail.com       null                             John Doe    No         Non-Privileged Support Account
mark.obrien@mail.com        obriem01                         Mark Obrien No         Mailbox

Extract AD on Azure



mail
OnPremisesSamAccountName
displayName
fromDistinguished




john.smith@mail.com
smithj01
John Smith
John Smith


john.doe@mail.com
doej01
Jonnie Doe
John Doe


jane.doe@mail.com
doej01
Jane Doe
Jane Doe



I've been trying to find the NHA_Derived_Responsible_Manager, and I succeeded in DAX, however, the requirements have changed and now I have to do it in PowerQuery:
ResponsibleManagerUsername = LOWER(
    COALESCE(
        IF(
            [Purpose] = "Privileged Support Account" || 
            [Purpose] = "Non-Privileged Support Account", 
            LOOKUPVALUE(
                'Extract AD on Azure'[onPremisesSamAccountName], 
                'Extract AD on Azure'[FromDistinguished], 
                [fullname]
            ),
            IF(
                [is_zz_em_] = "Yes", 
                LOOKUPVALUE(
                    'Extract AD on Azure'[onPremisesSamAccountName], 
                    'Extract AD on Azure'[mail], 
                    SUBSTITUTE([email], "zz_em_", "")
                ), 
                BLANK()
            )
        ),
        IF(
            [Purpose] = "Privileged Support Account" || 
            [Purpose] = "Non-Privileged Support Account", 
            LOOKUPVALUE(
                'Extract AD on Azure'[onPremisesSamAccountName], 
                'Extract AD on Azure'[displayName], 
                [fullname]
            ),
            BLANK()
        ),
        'Extract AD on Prem - NHA Insight'[NHA_Derived_Responsible_Manager]
    )
)

This snippet shows the logic that I need to have, three LOOKUPVALUEs based on three IF statements.
I need to change the existing Extract AD on Prem[NHA_Derived_Responsible_Manager] to include the OnPremisesSamAccountName.
I've tried a lot of different code to no avail and this is my most recent attempt:
 = Table.AddColumn(#"Trimmed Text1", "AzureUsername", each if [is_zz_em_] = "yes" then
        let
            EmailWithoutPrefix = Text.Remove([email], "zz_em_"),
            LookupRow = Table.SelectRows(#"Extract AD on Azure", each [mail] = EmailWithoutPrefix)
        in
            if Table.IsEmpty(LookupRow) then null else LookupRow{0}[onPremisesSamAccountName]
    else
        null)

I only tried to add a column with the lookup, but even that isn't working.
What I'm looking to do is filling out the NHA_Derived_Responsible_Manager column based on these three lookups/ifs:

if is_zz_em_ is 'Yes', extract the email without the prefix and look up the email in the Azure table
if the Purpose is Privileged Support Account or Non-Privileged, I want to look up the fullname both within fromDistinguished and displayName in Azure since the data isn't very consistent

Any help would be much appreciated!

this does an email match regardless of prefixes or suffixes
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table2"]}[Content],
#"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "Nha", (x)=>try Table.SelectRows(Table1, each  Text.Contains([mail],x[mail])){0}[Nha] otherwise null)
in  #"Added Custom"



I'm not entirely sure of your logic, but this code tries to mimic you IF statements.
let

//Read in both tables and set the data types
//NOTE: you can either do it this way or have the two tables in separate queries
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Azure"]}[Content],
    #"Extract AD on Azure" = 
        Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source), each {_, type text})),
   Source2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Prem"]}[Content],
    #"Extract AD on Prem" = 
        Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source2,List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(Source2), each {_,type text})),

//----------------------------------------------------
//Transform Manager column
    Manager = Table.FromRecords(
    
    Table.TransformRows(#"Extract AD on Prem", (r)=>
        Record.TransformFields(r, 
            {"NHA_Derived_Responsible_Manager", each 
                if r[Purpose] = "Non-Privileged Support Account" 
                    or r[Purpose] = "Privileged Support Account"
                then Table.SelectRows(#"Extract AD on Azure", each [fromDistinguished]=r[Fullname])[OnPremisesSamAccountName]{0}
    
                else try Table.SelectRows(#"Extract AD on Azure", each Text.Contains(r[Email],[mail]))[OnPremisesSamAccountName]{0}
                    otherwise _})))
in
    Manager

Data Tables

Results


Thank you for looking into it! What I'm looking to do is fill out the NHA_Derived_Responsible_Manager column so in the Results I'd have smithj01 and doej02 for Jane Doe and John Smith.

@01nowicj As your data exists, that would require some kind of fuzzy lookup as none of the emails in the Azure table match exactly with those in the Prem table, even after you remove the zz_em_. It can be done, but you need to lay out the rules for the fuzzy match. It could be as simple as replacing the underscore with a dot, or possibly more complex depending on how many errors there might be in your tables.

@01nowicj If your DAX code is working, I suspect you have typos in the data you have presented as an example.

Ah, apologies, there's a typo in my example. The emails look like zz_em_jane.doe@mail.com and zz_em_john.smith@mail.com so they do match. In the original data they do match. Thank you for pointing it out!

@01nowicj That makes things simpler. Code and screenshots have been edited. Note that your is_zz_em_ column is superfluous for this purpose.

Yes, it's more for quick testing/filtering later on, would you suggest not using it for this? I thought it'd be good to use it

@01nowicj As you can see from my code, it is not being used for the purpose of filling out the Manager column. And if you don't need it for anything else, it serves no purpose.

Thank you Ron, however I'm getting a cyclic reference error, and I'm not sure where it's coming from.

@01nowicj away from my computer now. Will check later today. Which step does the error first appear on?

@01nowicj Being concerned about typos in what I provided, I copy/pasted your data from your question, and the code I provided, and it completed without any errors. Either there is something about your actual data I did not take into account, or you did not properly adapt the code to your actual situation. Have you figured out anything since this morning?

No, I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong to be honest! I'm not sure why the cyclic reference error as your code also refers to the same table, I did however find a different solution which I'm testing at the moment. Thank you so much Ron!

@01nowicj On which of the applied steps does the error first appear?
